# Prolog not recursing as intended

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a function which takes in a list of lists, and I want to pattern match each int in the inner list to a specific pattern. There are 9 lists in the list of lists (call it A), and each list within the list also contains 9 ints. I want to use recursion to traverse down each list 3 at a time, and print appropriately, but I don't seem to be getting past the first step of recursion in my main function. 
Code for clarity:

```
print_tail([]).
print_tail([A,B,C|Ts]) :-
  write('print_tail called'), nl,
  print_tail_h(A,B,C),
  write('Recursed'),             % this never prints
  print_tail(Ts).                % this never happens

% working, or so it seems 
print_tail_h([A1,A2,A3|As],[B1,B2,B3|Bs],[C1,C2,C3|Cs]) :-
  printer([A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3]),nl,
  write('Helper recursed'), nl,
  print_tail_h(As, Bs, Cs).

printer([]).
printer([X|Xs]) :-
  write(X),
  printer(Xs).
```

I'm calling this function to test it:

```
test_print_tail :-
  X = [
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],   % stops recursing here
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]],
  print_tail(X).
```

My output is as follows:

```
print_tail called
123123123
Helper recursed
456456456
Helper recursed
789789789
Helper recursed
false.
```

I *feel like* it should work, but clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_tail_h` recursively calls itself, but there is no base case defined. Once As, Bs and Cs are empty, the predicate fails, which in turn causes `print_tail` to fail as well.

Simply add another clause to fix this:

```
print_tail_h([],[],[]).
```

Output:

```
print_tail called
123123123
Helper recursed
456456456
Helper recursed
789789789
Helper recursed
Recursedprint_tail called
123123123
Helper recursed
456456456
Helper recursed
789789789
Helper recursed
Recursedprint_tail called
123123123
Helper recursed
456456456
Helper recursed
789789789
Helper recursed
Recursed
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I completely didn't see that